# How to remove duplicated background image when adding HTML5 video?

Tags: css, html

I have added full screen HTML5 video. When page loads appears background image after 5s will start a video. Problem: before video starts i'm getting two background images on top of each see [EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xkc9z.jpg). I tried remove background or poster url, remove container div, change background-size nothing worked.

How to remove duplicated background image?

Maybe this code snippet is enough to solve the problem:

**HTML**

```
<!-- VIDEO-->

        <div class="container" id="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div align="center" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <video poster="img/background.jpg" class="embed-responsive-item" id="bg-vid">
                        <source src="CannonStreet_Timelapse_1280.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background: url("../img/background.jpg")no-repeat ;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

/***VIDEO***/


video#bg-vid {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background: url("../img/background.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: have you tried adding a width of 100% ?

Comment: Yes, but nothing changed.

Comment: can you provide the poster image you are using and few 2-3 seconds of the video please so I can check? Or may be the testing link where the site is live?

Comment: a jsfiddle will help us.

Comment: Here you go https://jsfiddle.net/w2fbdkv1/1/ . Maybe it helps to figure out.

Comment: Kindly use absolute image and video paths for jsfiddle like `url("http://www.example.com/image.gif")` rather than relative paths like `url("../img/background.jpg")`

Comment: Updated image and video url for jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/w2fbdkv1/5/